# Property pointer-events don't work in IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the best work around for the problem of the property pointer-events not working in IE9 and IE10?

Let say I have the HTML:

```
<div class="navigationmenu">
<ul>
  <li id="profilebtn">
    <img src="ui.png" width="27" height="24"/>
    <p>Home</p>
</li>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$('.navigationmenu').click(function (e)
{
    if(e.target.id == 'profilebtn')
        // DO SOMETHING;
}
```

How can I change this to make it work in IE9 and 10 without the pointer-events:none; in the child and pointer-events:auto; in the parent?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not bind the event to the li? or if the li is dynamic, delegate it to the li? any click events on it's children will propagate to the li where you can get the li's id.

Comment: Hi, thanks but in IE the event does not propagate. If an element is hover the li (img and p) then li will not receive the event.